# Javascript setTimeout function starts executing too many times

Tags: javascript, settimeout, intervals

I created a loop with setTimeout function and it comes to a problem after 2nd or 3rd step it call's itself because it starts excecuting twice at the time. This is what my function looks like:

```
var value = 70, 
    intervalID = null;

function interval() {
  intervalID = setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
}

function countDown() {
  value--;
  if(value > 0) {
    clearTimeout(intervalID);
    interval();
  } else {
    endInterval();
  }
}

function endInterval() {
  // do something
}
```

If I console the variable value its 69, 68 and after that it starts decreasing variable value twice in one function call. I'm not calling function countDown() anywhere but from one place.

[image: Javascript Interval]
What could be the problem?

Edit: this code works now.

Comment: Works fine for me - http://jsfiddle.net/wZ3GM/ You sure you aren't calling the initial function twice?

Comment: Actually a loop you didn't wrote in you code or the "timeout loop" created?

Comment: I had to clear timeout every time I called it again and it started working. Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend you to "sanitize" the timeouts by stopping previous one.

```
function interval() {
  clearTimeout(intervalID);
  intervalID = setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
}
```

However it looks like control of symptoms instead of sickness' cause. So it would be better to detect the cause of the issue.

Comment: No. A timeout does not need to be cleared from its own callback function.

Comment: I found out that I had 2 dom elements in the html with the same class so that's why everything started to execute twice.

Comment: @Bergi, you are right, but when you assign a timeout ID to global variable you never know if the previous timeout assigned to this variable is executed or not. I think it violates the integrity because we can count on the intervalID variable.

Comment: The OP's original solution did not use a timeoutID. And yes, you should never use global variables but closured ones for such tasks. Also, if you expect the timeoutID to be overwritten and want to clear previous ones, you would need to do that before overwriting it. Your approach clears only the "latest" assigned one when previous ones execute.